# ActiveModelSerializers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am using `active_model_serializers` in my app (for API's):

```
class TrainingModuleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :status, :module_type
  has_many :courses, serializer: CourseSerializer
end

class CourseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end

def training_module_list
  @training_modules = TrainingModule.where(tenant_id: 1)
  render :json => @training_modules
end
```

In some API's, I need to add courses data (there is `has_many` association with `training_module`), but in some API's I don't want to add courses data.

Can anybody explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create one more serializer without `has_many`

```
class SimpleTrainingModuleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :status, :module_type
end
```

and use it in the controller

```
render json: @record, serializer: SimpleTrainingModuleSerializer
```